# How to stream Azure Powershell output to Azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I have powershell cmdlets that output either a list or formatted as table.
I would like to stream the output to an azure table storage to be accessed by Power BI.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with Azure Storage Tables you don't have any way to directly stream to them but you can write data row by row.

Writing to a table is done like this

```
# Get the necessary modules, if needed. Latter one was not installed for me by running
# the top command.
# Install-Module AzureRM
# Install-Module AzureRMStorageTable

# Login to Azure RM model
Login-AzureRmAccount

# Some variables
$storageAccountName = <account name>
$tableName = <table name>
$partitionKey1 = <partition name
$rg = <resource group name>

# Get the storage account and its context
$storageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rg `
    -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

# Create a new table, if needed
# New-AzureStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx

# Get a reference to the table
$storageTable = Get-AzureStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx

# Add some rows into the table
Add-StorageTableRow `
    -table $storageTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"="Chris";"userid"=1}
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell) page for more detailed information on how to work with Azure Storage Tables using PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you!  the link is very informative.  I found this article that walks through the steps https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5330/exploring-azure-table-storage-with-powershell/